# How can you exclude a row from a SUM based on a cell's value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range that I want to sum, which is A2:M35. However, if column 'N' has the number 1 in it, I want to exclude that entire row from the sum. So, If N3 contains 1 I want to exclude the range A3:M3 from the sum calculation. Is this possible?

UPDATE:

I should also include that the 1 or 0 in column N is a flag to state whether this row should be excluded or not (1 = yes, 0 = no). However, this value is derived by checking whether any values in that row = "excluded". So, the additional complication here appears to be that even though the rows with "excluded" in them should be excluded, the sum calculation will show '#VALUE' as it believes some of the values are of the wrong data type (even though they shouldn't be included).

Comment: So, you could use sumproduct() and as the value in column N is 1 for yes and 0 for no then multiplying by 1 or 0 gives the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION (with helper column)**

If you can, to keep it simple, I'd just add a helper column.

So In cell O2:

```
=IF($N2=1,0,SUM($A2:$M2))
```

Drag that down to cell O35.
Then you can simply:

```
=SUM($O$2:$O$35)
```

**COMPLEX SOLUTION (no helper column)**

If you would like to avoid having to have a helper column cluttering up your sheet, you could use a SUMPRODUCT formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$M$35,(LEN($A$2:$M$35)-LEN($A$2:$M$35))+NOT($N$2:$N$35))
```

HOW IT WORKS:

The first range (A2:M35) is the array (or in this case a range of excel cells) that you want to sum.

The SUMPRODUCT is going to take each value in that array and multiply it by each corresponding value in the next array we supply, then sum all the results together.

The problem is that the first array is a table, 13 values across and 34 values down. The second array (column N) is only 1 value across. SUMPRODUCT requires that all arrays are the same size.

To do this, we first create an array the correct size:

```
(LEN(A2:M35)-LEN(A2:M35))
```

LEN returns an array containing the number of characters in each cell supplied to it. If we take it away from it's self, we are left with an array of the correct size, filled with zeros.

We can then add the values in our smaller array (column N) to the zeros in the array of the correct size, this will fill all the columns with the correct value.

```
+NOT(N2:N35))
```

The NOT is there because we want to sum the rows which have a zero. All it is doing is swapping the zeros and ones in column N. So, all 1's become 0's and vice versa.

I hope you can follow my explanation. If not, please let me know and I will elaborate.

Comment: Yes, this actually makes more sense to do it this way. I was over complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: It's often the way... but sometimes, you can't add that helper column for whatever reason and you have to resort to things like array formulas... bleurgh.

Comment: And that is often down to how you lay out the data on day 1, of course if it comes "as is" from elsewhere and you can't cjange it...